# Interaction analysis

Tags: r, interaction, bioinformatics

I have a question regarding non-additive interaction analysis in "R".

I know how to do use `lm` and `glm`, here I am working on a specific query. I need to do non-additive interaction analysis between SNP ( 0(homozygous minor), 1 (heterozygous), 2 (homozygous major)) and alcohol exposure (continuous variable) for a particular phenotype (categorical variable(cases/controls)).

According to my understanding, I will do that as:

```
my-fit = lm(outcome~SNP×alcohol exposure, data= data.frame)
```

I am not sure is that true or not. Can anyone please help me out on this query.

In addition it's a gene*environment analysis.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. Can you please help me out in resolving that?

Comment: Please explain to us, as quantitatively as possible, what a "non-additive interaction analysis" is.  Your notation does not appear to distinguish this from a routine interaction.